# How do I use the on_change method to calculate total current value

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

How do I make a value change in real time after I input a specific field value in a form? e.g from the screenshot below , if I enter Quantity recieved as 10000 the Actual stock should compute to 80500.

so far this is the code for the on_change method I came up with :
I would like to know whether this is the correct approach

```py
@api.one
@api.onchange('qnty_recieved', 'init_stock')
def _compute_current_stock(self):

    qnty_recieved = self.qnty_recieved
    init_stock = self.init_stock
    current_quantity = self.current_quantity

    self.current_quantity = self.qnty_recieved + self.init_stock
```

Below is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535513/how-to-make-a-field-update-values-in-realtime-after-inputting-a-value-from-an-ex).

Comment: @Naglis Your link is dead.

Comment: @travisw, the other question was removed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not wrong you want to change your actual stock in real time based on quantity received field.

This can be best achieved by using depends method.

```
@api.one
@api.depends('qnty_recieved')
def _compute_current_stock(self):

    # Assuming current_quantity as the field name of actual stock
    self.current_quantity += self.qnty_recieved
```

You should also add 
`compute=_compute_current_stock, store=True` keyword arguments to your actual stock field.

Comment: Thanks @Adhithiya for the tip.